# vue + firebase auth output console.log of auth/internal-error instead auth/invalid-password

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to test authentication of my simple vue application that using firebase, but the console.log of its error give output "auth/internal-error" instead "auth/invalid-password" when I give empty password

> Firebase: An internal AuthError has occurred. (auth/internal-error).

```
<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const email = ref('')
const password = ref('')
const errMsg = ref()
const router = useRouter()
const login = () => {
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
        .then((data) => {
        console.log('Successfully logged in!');
        router.push('/dashboard')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;   
            console.log(error.message);
        })
}
```

Comment: What else does the `error.message` contain?

`auth/internal-error`: The Authentication server encountered an unexpected error while trying to process the request. **The error message should contain the response from the Authentication server containing additional information**. [source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not allow the request with an empty password. Handle the error before, when you know it will happen.

Comment: I think this is best solution so far for this problem, thanks for the answer. i will add validation for the input. But i'm still curious why empty password get different error message from firebase

Comment: Most likely because firebase expects it, and deem the request invalid.